# Single Column Huge table (2.5 B rows). Clustered index Vs Clustered Columnstore index

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, clustered-index, columnstore, filegroup

We are having a huge table Table1(2.5 billion rows) with single column A(NVARCHAR(255) datatype). What is the right approach for seek operations against this table. Clustered index on A Vs Clustered Column store index on A.

We are already keeping this table in separate filegroup from the other table Table2, with which it will be Joined.

Do you suggest partitioning this table for better performance ? This column will have unicode data also. So, what kind of partitioning approach is fine for unicode datatype ?

UPDATE: To clarify further, the use case for the table is SEEK. The table is storing identifiers for individuals. The major concerns here are performance for SEEK in the case of huge table. This table will be referred inside a transaction. We want the transaction to be short.

Comment: How frequently we do Inserts and updates on this table? Do you require fast query response on SELECTIVITY and inserts updates can be slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustered index vs column store index depends on the use case for the table. Column store keeps track of unique entries in the column and the rows where those entries are stored. This makes it very useful for data warehousing tasks such as aggregates against the indexed columns, however not as optimal for transactional tasks that need to pull a small number of specific rows. If you are using SQL Server 2014 or later you can use both a clustered index and a columnstore index by creating a clustered columnstore index. It does have some limitations and overhead that you should read up on though.

Given that this is a seek for specific rows and not an aggregation of the column, I would recommend a clustered index instead of a column store index.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated the question to provide more information. As the table is having single column, I dont know how clustered index performance differs from clustered column store index performance here.

Comment: Do you mean there is only one column in this table, or this one column is the only one you are concerned about for this use case? If you have a table that consists of only one column, I'm somewhat confused as to what purpose it would serve. As for the clustered index vs column store index, a column store would be better for aggregates where a clustered index would be better for fetching rows. A clustered column store index is a combination of both but has a larger overhead and its own limitations.

Comment: Yes. it is a table with single column only. We are having this as part of our stop gap arrangement to validate the individuals against this table to filter them out for our needs. As it is a single column table, I want to understand the best case scenario for storage, for best performance of SEEKs.

Comment: A clustered index is all you need. You can partition it if the values increment in a known pattern, but if not then I don't know how you would partition it.

Comment: can you please update your answer accordingly. I will accept the answer. It is a ALPHANUMERIC field and can have unicode values. I am not sure about the right partitioning approach to balance the data. I will check accordingly.

Comment: Edited. In order for partitioning to be helpful you would have to sort your values and partition by the sort order. You can take a look at http://technologycraftsmen.net/blog/2010/10/19/alphanumeric-sorting-in-mssql/ for assigning a sort value. If you pull multiple values in a transaction then it would be best if they are grouped together in the same partition. If they are random then you will still need to hit multiple partitions, diminishing the value of partitioning. I hope this helps, I've only ever partitioned off of dates.